# Python Azure Function does not install 'extras' requirements

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-functions, requirements.txt

I have an azure function that depends on extras of a specific library, however it seems that Functions is ignoring the extras specified in the `requirements.txt`

I have specified this in the requirements.txt:

```
functown>=2.0.0
functown[jwt]>=2.0.0
```

This should install additional dependencies (`python-jose` in this case), however it seems like the extras are ignored by Azure functions:

```
 No module named 'jose'. Please check the requirements.txt file for the missing module.
```

I also tested this locally and can confirm that for a regular `pip install -r requirements.txt` the extras are picked up and `python-jose` is indeed installed (which I can verify by `import jose`).

Are there special settings to be set in Azure Function or is this a bug?

**Update 1:**

In particular I want to install the dependencies on an extra of a python library (defined [here](https://github.com/felixnext/python-functown/blob/d2034609586ed133be5947983549addde97e7879/setup.py#L71) and reqs [here](https://github.com/felixnext/python-functown/blob/main/requirements-jwt.txt)), which works perfectly when setting up a local environment on my system. So I assume it is not a python or requirements problem. However, it does **not** work when deploying to Azure Functions, leading me to assume that there is an inherent problem with Azure Functions picking up `extras` requirements?

Answer (score 0):

***I have reproduced from my end and got below results.***

**Test Case 1**:

With the `functown` Python Package, I have tested in Azure Functions Python Version 3.9 Http Trigger with the below Code:

****init**.py**:

```py
import  logging
from  logging  import  Logger
from  functown  import  ErrorHandler
import  azure.functions  as  func

@ErrorHandler(debug=True, enable_logger=True)
def  main(req: func.HttpRequest, logger: Logger, **kwargs) -> func.HttpResponse:
logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

a = 3
b= 5
if  a > b:
raise  ValueError("something went wrong")
else:
print ("a is less than b")

return  func.HttpResponse("Hello Pravallika, This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.", status_code=200)
```

**requirements.txt**:

```
azure-functions
functown
```

[image]

**Test Case 2**:

This is with the `Python-Jose` and `Jose` Libraries in Azure Functions Python v3.9 Http Trigger:

[image]

****init**.py**:

```py
import  logging
from  logging  import  Logger
from  functown  import  ErrorHandler
import  azure.functions  as  func
from  jose  import  jwt

@ErrorHandler(debug=True, enable_logger=True)
def  main(req: func.HttpRequest, logger: Logger, **kwargs) -> func.HttpResponse:
logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

# Sample Code Test with functown Packages in Azure Functions Python Http Trigger
a = 3
b= 5
if  a > b:
raise  ValueError("something went wrong")
else:
print ("a is less than b")

# Sample Code Test with Jose, Python-Jose Packages in Azure Functions Python Http Trigger
token = jwt.encode({'key': 'value'}, 'secret', algorithm='HS256')
u'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJrZXkiOiJ2YWx1ZSJ9.FG-8UppwHaFp1LgRYQQeS6EDQF7_6-bMFegNucHjmWg'
print(token)

jwt.decode(token, 'secret', algorithms=['HS256'])
{u'key': u'value'}
print(token)

return  func.HttpResponse("Hello Pravallika, This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.", status_code=200)
```

**requirements.txt**:

```
azure-functions
functown
jose
Python-jose
```

Code Samples taken from the references [doc1](https://jose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [doc1](https://pypi.org/project/python-jose/).

For your error, I suggest you:

1. check the code how you imported the modules such as `Jose`, `functown` in the code as I seen similar issue in the SO #[61061435](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61061435/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-jose) where users given code snippet for how to import the Jose Packages and the above code snippets I have provided in practical.
2. Make sure you have Virtual Environment installed in your Azure Functions Python Project for running the Python Functions.

Comment: Not sure I understand the solution here. I can confirm that it will work as intended when I put python-jose in the requirements.txt. However, that is not what I want to do. Rather I want to install the extras of the library (as it is more dynamic) by putting `functown[jwt]` in my requriements.txt. This works fine in local environment but it seems that Azure Functions have a problem with that! (Also added that info as update ot the main question)